# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: three.js

I am currently trying to run my three.js project, however the following error keeps appearing in the console:

127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I've come to a dead end as to what could be going wrong, because the path name to three and its component seem to be correct. There is no error while loading the resources.

(see image)

[no errors loading js files in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0s5D.png)

[express server with static paths to three in node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl4mb.png)

[js referencing to those paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HllOP.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb56G.png)

Would any one be able to help?

Thank you :)

Comment: Consider to organize your project like in the following example: https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm. Especially use a build tool like `rollup`.